# AngularJS $http.post 404 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I am a new user to Angular.JS, but I like the SPA essence of it. However, when I tried to use `$http.post`, I get a 404 error. Here is my code for the file that has the 404:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('jerri')
    .controller('SignUpController', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', function($scope, $state, $http){
      $scope.createUser = function(){
        console.log($scope.newUser);
        $http.post('api/users/signup', $scope.newUser).success(function(response){

        });
      }
    }]);
}());
```

And my error:

```
angular.js:11821 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/signup 404 (Not Found)
```

Now, despite my ignorance, I referred to Google for several hours. I got to many posts here on Stack Overflow as well as the AngularJS Website, but I have found nothing that has worked at the moment.

Would anybody mind helping me out with this likely rookie mistake? Thank you in advance.

Tavin

Comment: Have you tried checking you backend api? you can use tools like `Postman` which simulate http clients

Comment: So what is the problem? 404 is the simplest kind of errors - just correct url/backend routes. However, this is kind of errors that are hard to help with. You are alone.